# music player - read storage permissions issue

Tags: java, android, audio-player, android-music-player

Im having problem with permissions for reading storage in my phone. I have to list all audio files in my phone so I have tried to ask for permisiion with "activitycompact.requestPermissions" The only problem is, that when application is installed and firstly opened it says "MusicPlayer has stopped" and after that dialog it open request for Permissions, so I allow it and then I had to reopen this file. I dont know how to ask for those permissions before it crashes.

Main Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

private static final int UPDATE_FREQUENCY = 500;
private static final int STEP_VALUE = 4000;
private MediaCursorAdapter mediaAdapter = null;
private TextView selectedFile= null;
private SeekBar seekbar = null;
private MediaPlayer player = null;
private ImageButton playButton = null;
private ImageButton previousButton = null;
private  ImageButton nextButton = null;
private boolean isStarted = true;
private  String currentFile = "";
private boolean isMovingseekBar = false;
private final Handler handler = new Handler();
private final Runnable updatePositionRunnable = new Runnable() {
    public  void run() {
        updatePosition();

    }
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                1);

    selectedFile = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.selectedfile);
    seekbar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekbar);
    playButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.play);
    previousButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.previous);
    nextButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.next);

    player = new MediaPlayer();

    player.setOnCompletionListener(onCompletion);
    player.setOnErrorListener(onError);
    seekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(seekBarChanged);
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

    if (null != cursor) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        mediaAdapter = new MediaCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.listitem, cursor);
        setListAdapter(mediaAdapter);
        playButton.setOnClickListener(onButtonClick);
        nextButton.setOnClickListener(onButtonClick);
        previousButton.setOnClickListener(onButtonClick);
    }
}
@Override
protected  void onListItemClick(ListView list, View view, int position,long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(list, view, position, id);
    currentFile = (String) view.getTag();
    startPlay(currentFile);
}
@Override
protected void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();

    handler.removeCallbacks(updatePositionRunnable);
    player.stop();
    player.reset();
    player.release();

    player = null;
}
private  void startPlay(String file) {
    selectedFile.setText(file);
    seekbar.setProgress(0);

    player.stop();
    player.reset();

    try {
        player.setDataSource(file);
        player.prepare();
        player.start();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    seekbar.setMax(player.getDuration());
    playButton.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.ic_media_pause);

    updatePosition();

    isStarted = true;

}

private void stopPlay() {
    player.stop();
    player.reset();
    playButton.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.ic_media_play);
    handler.removeCallbacks(updatePositionRunnable);
    seekbar.setProgress(0);

    isStarted = false;
}
private void updatePosition() {
    handler.removeCallbacks(updatePositionRunnable);

    handler.postDelayed(updatePositionRunnable, UPDATE_FREQUENCY);
}


private class MediaCursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter{

    MediaCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c){
        super(context, layout,c,
                new String[] {MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns.DURATION},
                new int[] {R.id.displayname, R.id.title,R.id.duration});
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view,Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        TextView title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
        TextView name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.displayname);
        TextView duration = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.duration);

        name.setText(cursor.getString(
                cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME)));

        title.setText(cursor.getString(
                cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE)));

        view.setTag(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA)));
    }
    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem, parent, false);

        bindView(v, context, cursor);

        return v;
    }
}



private View.OnClickListener onButtonClick  = new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.play: {
                if (player.isPlaying()) {
                    handler.removeCallbacks(updatePositionRunnable);
                    player.pause();
                    playButton.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.ic_media_play);
                } else {
                    if (isStarted) {
                        player.start();
                        playButton.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.ic_media_pause);
                        updatePosition();
                    } else {
                        startPlay(currentFile);
                    }
                }
                break;
            }
            case R.id.next: {
                int seekto = player.getCurrentPosition() + STEP_VALUE;

                if (seekto < player.getDuration())
                    seekto = player.getDuration();
                player.pause();
                player.seekTo(seekto);
                player.start();

                break;
            }
            case R.id.previous: {
                int seekto = player.getCurrentPosition() - STEP_VALUE;

                if (seekto < player.getDuration())
                    seekto = player.getDuration();

                player.pause();
                player.seekTo(seekto);
                player.start();

                break;

            }
        }
    }
};
private MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener onCompletion = new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {

    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        stopPlay();
    }
};

private MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener onError = new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {

        return false;
    }
};


private SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener seekBarChanged = new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        isMovingseekBar = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fomUser) {
        if (isMovingseekBar) {
            player.seekTo(progress);
            Log.i("OnSeekBarChangeListener", "onProgressChange");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        isMovingseekBar = true;
    }
};
```

Comment: Post the logcat error here.

Comment: Did you add the required permissions in your manifest?

Comment: I think you are missing permission in manifest or if you are trying to run the app on 6.0 or above then you need to ask for permission on run time.

Answer (score 0):

1) Please make sure you have added the permission in Manifest.XML

2) I can not see anything like you are handling the requested permission   result.

Remove below from your onCreate

```
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

    if (null != cursor) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        mediaAdapter = new MediaCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.listitem, cursor);
        setListAdapter(mediaAdapter);
}
```

and keep in side of

```
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
            String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {

    if(requestCode ==YOUR_REQ_CODE) {

     if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    //Do your  stuff here.
 } 
    }
```

Comment: It's not necessarily the best idea to do stuff in `onRequestPermissionsResult`. If permission already granted, there is no reason to request anything in the first place, hense that method would not be called.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,
 Add this in onCreate()

```
if( checkIfAlreadyhavePermission(activity, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) ){

// Add the code here the code you need to work after accepting permission

player = new MediaPlayer();

player.setOnCompletionListener(onCompletion);
player.setOnErrorListener(onError);
seekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(seekBarChanged);
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

if (null != cursor) {
    cursor.moveToFirst();

    mediaAdapter = new MediaCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.listitem, cursor);
    setListAdapter(mediaAdapter);
  }
    }else {
        requestForSpecificPermission(
                activity, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    }
```

And add this to MainActivity

```
public  boolean checkIfAlreadyhavePermission(Activity activity, String permission) {
    int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, permission);
    if (result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
public  void requestForSpecificPermission(Activity activity, String granted_permission) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity,  new String[]{granted_permission}, 101);

    }
}
```

**Please note** if you have only permission issue it will work. Please share your logcat

Answer (score 0):

when ask permission use below code ..

```
 if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(EdittextActivity.this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(EdittextActivity.this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                    WriteBtn(view); // hear define your code after getting permission.
                }
                else {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(EdittextActivity.this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
                }
            }
```

also when you allow permission and call your particular method that time used below code ..

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if (requestCode==1){
        display(); // call your method that required permission.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**May this help you :**

```
--------------------------------
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> 

 Add this line in manifest

 if any error then 
    <permission
    android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
  - Optional 


------------------------------

public class PermissionUtils 
{

Context context;
Activity current_activity;

PermissionResultCallback permissionResultCallback;


ArrayList<String> permission_list=new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> listPermissionsNeeded=new ArrayList<>();
String dialog_content="";
int req_code;

public PermissionUtils(Context context)
{
    this.context=context;
    this.current_activity= (Activity) context;

    permissionResultCallback= (PermissionResultCallback) context;
}


/**
 * Check the API Level & Permission
 *
 * @param permissions
 * @param dialog_content
 * @param request_code
 */

public void check_permission(ArrayList<String> permissions, String dialog_content, int request_code)
{
    this.permission_list=permissions;
    this.dialog_content=dialog_content;
    this.req_code=request_code;

   if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23)
   {
       if (checkAndRequestPermissions(permissions, request_code))
       {
           permissionResultCallback.PermissionGranted(request_code);
           Log.i("all permissions", "granted");
           Log.i("proceed", "to callback");
       }
   }
    else
   {
       permissionResultCallback.PermissionGranted(request_code);

       Log.i("all permissions", "granted");
       Log.i("proceed", "to callback");
   }

}


/**
 * Check and request the Permissions
 *
 * @param permissions
 * @param request_code
 * @return
 */

private  boolean checkAndRequestPermissions(ArrayList<String> permissions, int request_code) {

    if(permissions.size()>0)
    {
        listPermissionsNeeded = new ArrayList<>();

        for(int i=0;i<permissions.size();i++)
        {
            int hasPermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(current_activity,permissions.get(i));

            if (hasPermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                listPermissionsNeeded.add(permissions.get(i));
            }

        }

        if (!listPermissionsNeeded.isEmpty())
        {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(current_activity, listPermissionsNeeded.toArray(new String[listPermissionsNeeded.size()]),request_code);
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}

/**
 *
 *
 * @param requestCode
 * @param permissions
 * @param grantResults
 */
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults)
{
    switch (requestCode)
    {
        case 1:
             if(grantResults.length>0)
             {
                 Map<String, Integer> perms = new HashMap<>();

                 for (int i = 0; i < permissions.length; i++)
                 {
                     perms.put(permissions[i], grantResults[i]);
                 }

                 final ArrayList<String> pending_permissions=new ArrayList<>();

                 for (int i = 0; i < listPermissionsNeeded.size(); i++)
                 {
                     if (perms.get(listPermissionsNeeded.get(i)) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                     {
                        if(ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(current_activity,listPermissionsNeeded.get(i)))
                                pending_permissions.add(listPermissionsNeeded.get(i));
                        else
                        {
                            Log.i("Go to settings","and enable permissions");
                            permissionResultCallback.NeverAskAgain(req_code);
                           // Toast.makeText(current_activity, "Go to settings and enable permissions", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            return;
                        }
                     }

                 }

                 if(pending_permissions.size()>0)
                 {
                     showMessageOKCancel(dialog_content,
                             new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                 @Override
                                 public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                                     switch (which) {
                                         case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                                             check_permission(permission_list,dialog_content,req_code);
                                             break;
                                         case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
                                             Log.i("permisson","not fully given");
                                             if(permission_list.size()==pending_permissions.size())
                                                 permissionResultCallback.PermissionDenied(req_code);
                                             else
                                                 permissionResultCallback.PartialPermissionGranted(req_code,pending_permissions);
                                             break;
                                     }


                                 }
                             });

                 }
                 else
                 {
                    Log.i("all","permissions granted");
                    Log.i("proceed","to next step");
                     permissionResultCallback.PermissionGranted(req_code);

                 }



             }
             break;
    }
}


/**
 * Explain why the app needs permissions
 *
 * @param message
 * @param okListener
 */
private void showMessageOKCancel(String message, DialogInterface.OnClickListener okListener) {
    new AlertDialog.Builder(current_activity)
            .setMessage(message)
            .setPositiveButton("Ok", okListener)
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", okListener)
            .create()
            .show();
   }

 }

 =============================


    // You can add any permission here

    ArrayList<String> permissions = new ArrayList<>();
    PermissionUtils permissionUtils;


    permissionUtils = new PermissionUtils(context);

    permissions.add(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

    //i.e permissions.add(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

    permissionUtils.check_permission(permissions,getResources()
   .getString(R.string.explain_here_why_the_app_needs_permissions), 1);


 =============================

 Activty that implements PermissionResultCallback

 ===================

 Make interface

 public interface PermissionResultCallback
 {
  void PermissionGranted(int request_code);
  void PartialPermissionGranted(int request_code, ArrayList<String> 
                                                granted_permissions);
  void PermissionDenied(int request_code);
  void NeverAskAgain(int request_code);
 }

-----------------------------
```

Comment: can't understand what is wrong in my code can you please brief me

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code specifically (apart from the fact that it doesn't fully follow Java naming conventions). Your answer is only the code, without justification for any of it.

Comment: ok bro next time i will take care of it thanks for your valuable response